# This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57

Tags: node.js, canvas, npm, nvm

I was using Node.js v8.9.4 and since it's now EOL I decided to switch over to lts/erbium -> v12.14.1. In addition am using nvm (0.33.8) to handle my node versions.

I installed all packages fine with the exception of [canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas). After a successful installation using npm install canvas@latest I came upon an issue trying to use it to my Nodejs app. Here is the error.

```
Error: The module '/home/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

I have tried to completely uninstall and remove the canvas package from the node_modules file. Then to fix the above issued I tried:

```
npm rebuild canvas --update-binary
npm rebuild canvas --build-from-source
npm rebuild
```

but none work.

Comment: Remove package from your project and try with `npm install canvas --build-from-source`

Comment: I have already tried that.

Comment: anyone found any solution?